# How i can list all elements of rows if i have Schema.ObjectId in my model (similar where MYSQL)?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have 2 schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var companySchema= new Schema({  
    name: String,
    country: String       
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

and Groups(1 company can have many groups and each group can have group parent) :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var Company= mongoose.model('Company');
var Group= mongoose.model('Group');


var groupSchema = new Schema({  
    name: String,       
    company: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Company" } ,
    parent_group: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Group" } ,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Group", groupSchema );
```

In my Group Controller i want to list groups belonging to company, because in my view i have 2 select and select of group change when change company select.

i have these in my controller:

```
    //GET /services/groups/:company

    exports.groupsByCompany=function(req,res){

     var company=req.params.company;

     Group.find({company:company},function(err,groups){
      Company.populate(groups,{
        path:'company',
        populate:{path:'group'}
        },function(err,groups){
          res.status(200).send(groups)
           });  
    });
      Group.find()        
    }
```

I also have problem with populate for get group parent collection, only return ID group Parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To populate group with data, try

```
Group.find({'company': company}).exec(function(err, group) {
    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    group.populate('company parent_group', function(err, group) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(group);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Boris but i try this and generate error :schema hasn't been registered for model

Comment: Have you imported in file (module), in which you perform search, the model itself: 
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var Group = mongoose.model('Gorup'); ? Also try to delete import of Group in groupSchema

Comment: i try this but not work  ..i dont know where is error

Comment: Keep in mind that mongoose model is imported in app.js and also in module (file) itself.